# How to granting permissions to randomly create service account on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-deployment-manager

I trying to create a deployment package on GCP with a customized VM Image. I do follow [docs](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/vm/test-product#preview_and_test_your_product) but as soon as I trigger the deployment, validation failed with the following error:

```
    "domain": "global",
        "message": "Required 'compute.images.useReadOnly' permission for 'projects/r-public/global/images/my-image'",
        "reason": "forbidden"
```

The problem is that the GCP console create for every trigger a new service account which has the permission issue. What could be the valid solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be you need to grant all authenticated Compute Engine users the Compute Image User role (roles/compute.imageUser) to a custom image.

To make images public, use the gcloud compute images add-iam-policy-binding command:
gcloud compute images add-iam-policy-binding IMAGE_NAME 
--member='allAuthenticatedUsers' 
--role='roles/compute.imageUser'

Replace IMAGE_NAME with the name of the resource—for example, my_image.

For more information on custom images access follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/managing-access-custom-images#share-images-publicly).

Comment: Apparently there's been an update to the `add-iam-policy-binding` command. It now expects a `POLICY_FILE` that contains the binding information. `--member` and `--role` arguments are no longer recognized. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/setIamPolicy for the correct docs POST request required. The docs for using the gcloud command is still not updated: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/add-iam-policy-binding